# Rollback a transaction on NHibernate and Enterprise Library

Tags: c#, nhibernate, transactions, enterprise-library, rollback

I have an web application that has multiple subsystems. In one of these subsystems I use NHibernate and in another I use Enterprise Library for data access layer.
Now I have a page that work with these two subsystems concurrently and when I click in a button in my page, execute two work.
My question is that if my application dealing with errors, How can I rollback all of works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not sure about enterprise library, but [nHibernate is claimed to play well](http://ayende.com/blog/1419/nhibernate-and-system-transactions-a-success) with `System.Transactions`

Comment: have you looked at the link provided? I think it's pretty clear. Is there anything specific you don't understand?